Как создать виртуальную лабораторию на сайте?
Пишу сайт на django, на котором можно будет писать код программ, выполнять их, получать результаты и т.д.
Сам django использует базу postgress на docker compose
И у меня возник вопрос, а как создать виртуальную лабораторию?
Т.е. Например такой код:
def printHi():
    print("Hi")

В питоне этом можно сделать с помощью функции eval()
Но как это выполнить на других языках? Есть ли общая система для выполнения кода с сайта?
Где-то я видел записи о том, что для этого создается шаблон докер контейнера, который в свою очень получает файл, выполняет и выводит обратно результат. Но не я не уверен, что такой способ является правильным.
Так же вариант есть с subprocess, но он тоже кажется не правильным, не оптимальным
